# Xamarin.Form CollectionView is checking RadioButtons randomly

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have been trying to figure out this issue for days but without any progress.

In my project, I am generating questionnaire, which do achieved by a page with RadioButtons in pair - group. Those groups are repeating in CollectionView.

Even though each RadioButton group has its own GroupName, it is happening that upon radiobutton click and scrolling down other radio button is clicked as well. Also then if I am scrolling back and forth, others radio buttons are clicked.

This is really strange behaviour for me.
Initially I have following selection (left picture) and after scrolling up and down, it looks like right picture.

[image]
[image]

The code is really simple.

XAML page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile.ViewModels"
             xmlns:commonLogic="clr-namespace:Mobile.Models;assembly=Mobile"
             xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms"
             xmlns:behaviorsPack="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Mobile;assembly=Mobile"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             x:Class="Mobile.Views.QuestionarePage"
             x:DataType="local:QuestionnaireViewModel"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
             Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
             Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.QuestionnaireTitle}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:QuestionnaireViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <CollectionView x:Name="listView"  ItemsSource="{Binding StringQuestions}" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout  Padding="10,5,10,8" Spacing="2" x:DataType="commonLogic:TestClass">
                        <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" FontSize="18"/>
                        <RadioButton  GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton  GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"  Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                        </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class TestClass 
{
public string GroupName { get; set; }

public TestClass(string name)
{
    GroupName = name;
}
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

**Update**

```
Even following code is causing me troubles
    <CollectionView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout  Padding="10,5,10,8" Spacing="2" >
                    <Label Text="TEST" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                    <RadioButton/>
                    <RadioButton/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: 1) What platform (Android, iOS, UWP)? 2) Show the class that contains `StringQuestions`, and the method that created the testdata you show. 3) Click only one button, then scroll. Do you still get multiple ones? 4) Does the one you DID click ever get UNSELECTED merely by scrolling? (so the selection has completely changed). 5) Add a button and put a breakpoint in its click method. After scrolling, click button. Examine data - does it match what you are seeing, re which ones are selected?

Comment: 6) Add a method that runs when a radio button changes state (checked to unchecked or vice versa). Put breakpoint there. It should only fire when you click the first button. Scrolling shouldn't cause it to fire again, AFAIK. To prove it is just some display glitch involving CollectionView + RadioButtons. 7) remove `x:DataType="commonLogic:TestClass"`. If this fixes it, then there is some issue with compiled bindings.

Comment: 8) Any error messages or warning in Debug Output?

Comment: 1) The issue is on iOS. It looks like Android works fine.
2) I have already change the code, but if I simplify it according to paint 7, no class is used.
3) Yes, I do
4) Sometimes it does - but now, since I removed binding in 7) it looks like it does not.
5) It looks like also data are not correct.

Comment: 6) I have binded IsSelected property, different for each radio button. (IsSelectedFirst, IsSelectedSecond, etc ..) Then I added breakpoint and I can see that SETTER is indeed triggered, while releasing finger from the screen. The same was happening with event, which was fired as well. How is that possible?
7) The issue still happening, but behaves different. Now, if I select first button, 10th button is selected as well. Looks like those groups are somehow connected.
8) No error/warnings. 7) is really strange. By that I have cut off all binding logic and the issues is still happening.

Comment: Please see updated XAML file above, where binding was removed from RadioButtons.

Comment: I agree that this is a strange symptom. It seems suspiciously like a Xamarin Bug when Radio Buttons are used in a CollectionView's ItemTemplate. But I don't see any similar "issue" (bug report) at the Xamarin Forms github repo. Sorry, I don't have more time to investigate - and since no one else has responded to your Q, it may not be an issue anyone is aware of.

Comment: Now that you've reduced it down to minimal code, it would be worth creating an issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues. You are welcome to go ahead and create that issue, with the explanation and minimal code you've given here. (Even better: create a public github repo, that anyone can download/build/run to see the symptom. This makes it MUCH more likely that someone will test and verify the problem.) Include a link back to this SO post.  And then post a link here, to the new issue you made.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below two methods.

**One**,using `ListView` to replace `CollectionView`.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"  HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding StringQuestions}" SelectionMode="None" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout  Padding="10,5,10,8" Spacing="2" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding GroupName}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="AliceBlue" FontSize="18"/>
                    <RadioButton   Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton   Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Two**:define two property in your model.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstCheck { get; set; }
    public bool IsSecondCheck { get; set; }
    public TestClass(string name)
    {
        GroupName = name;
    }
}
```

then bind to your RadioButtons:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="listView"  ItemsSource="{Binding StringQuestions}" SelectionMode="None" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout  Padding="10,5,10,8" Spacing="2" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding GroupName}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="AliceBlue" FontSize="18"/>
                    <RadioButton   IsChecked="{Binding IsFirstCheck}" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton   IsChecked="{Binding IsSecondCheck}" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged_1" Content="{Binding GroupName}"></RadioButton>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

in your code behind,change the `IsFirstCheck` and `IsSecondCheck` values.

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    
        TestClass test = (TestClass)(sender as RadioButton).BindingContext;
        if (test !=null)
        {
            test.IsFirstCheck = e.Value;
        }  
    
    }

private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass test = (TestClass)(sender as RadioButton).BindingContext;
        if (test != null)
        {
            test.IsSecondCheck = e.Value;
        }
    }
```